# having trouble with a Database query

Tags: sql, database

I'm studying for a database exam on the 6th of may and I'm having trouble wrapping my head around query from a previous years paper. I am trying to do part 'd' (4 in list).

So far I have this but dont know how to finish it

```
select count(*) as peopleOlderThanEmployeeNo100 
from EMPLOYEE, DEPT
where (dept.name = 'finance') and  (employee.dateOfBirth < ?);
```

**Question 4**

An SQL database has the following tables:

```
[EMPLOYEE]    
  [EmpNo]       Integer  (Primary Key) 
  [Name]        Char(30) 
  [Salary]      Decimal(7,2)
  [StartDate]   Date 
  [DateOfBirth] Date 
  [Dept]        Char(12)  (Foreign key references DEPT( Name ) )

[DEPT]
  [Name]       Char(12)  (Primary Key) 
  [CostCentre] Char(4)
```

Write SQL statements to do the following:

1. List the names all employees in the “Finance” department.
2. List the name and cost centre of all employees in “Finance” or “R&D”.
3. List the number of employees in the “Production” department.
4. **List the number of “Finance” employees who are older than employee number 100.**
5. List the name, department and salary of all employees in ascending order of department and salary.
6. Create an index on the EMPLOYEE table StartDate column.
7. List the oldest employee in the company.
8. Change the salary of employee 100 to 50,000.

Comment: So what have you tried so far, and what exactly was the problem with it?

Comment: Ive being trying queries similar to this                                                        select count(*) as peopleOlderThanEmployeeNo100 from EMPLOYEE, DEPT where (dept.name = 'finance') and (employee.dateOfBirth < ?);

Comment: I have to part d select the amount of people in finance who are older than empNo 100. Ive done a database assignment already worth 50% of my grade but I have an exam on wednesday worth the other 50%. as I looked over previous papers I started doing the above queries but cant do part d

Comment: @user3308338 so you need to find the age of employee 100, you can do this with a sub-query where the `?` is.

Comment: not his age, well i suppose I'll need it for the query, I need to find everyone in the finance department that's older than him

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery like this

```
select count(*) as peopleOlderThanEmployeeNo100 
from EMPLOYEE, DEPT
where (dept.name = 'Finance') 
and  (employee.dateOfBirth < (select dateOfBirth 
                              from EMPLOYEE 
                              where EmpNo = 100));
```

Comment: I got the solution from one of my class mates, it was pretty much the exact same as what you have, cheers for the input, there appears to be very similar queries to this in all previous exam papers, hopefully I should pass this exam tomorrow